# Ubuntu 14.04 GPU passthrough problem with IOMMU

Tags: kvm-virtualization, gpu, qemu

I have a problem with my GPU passthrough on Ubuntu 14.04, i checked my hard ware and my CPU is i7-2600 which supports VT-x in KVM and i try to passthrough my GTX 960. I did everything exactly as in [the pudgetsystems guide](https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/articles/Multiheaded-NVIDIA-Gaming-using-Ubuntu-14-04-KVM-585/). The error i get when i try to launch my VM:

```
# boris@boris-H61M-S2V-B3:~$ sudo /usr/vm1
[sudo] password for boris: 

qemu-system-x86_64: -device vfio-pci,host=0000:01:00.0,bus=root.1,addr=00.0,multifunction=on,x-vga=on: vfio: error no iommu_group for device
qemu-system-x86_64: -device vfio-pci,host=0000:01:00.0,bus=root.1,addr=00.0,multifunction=on,x-vga=on: Device initialization failed.
qemu-system-x86_64: -device vfio-pci,host=0000:01:00.0,bus=root.1,addr=00.0,multifunction=on,x-vga=on: Device 'vfio-pci' could not be initialized
```

Answer (score 0):

You also have to own a compatible motherboard.

Did you enable VT-x and VT-d in your bios?

Did you blacklist your card's kernel driver in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`? If not, append `blacklist nouveau` to the end of the file.

Double-check your `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules`, `/etc/default/grub`, `/etc/modules`, and `/etc/vfio-pci#.cfg` files. (Making sure to run `update-grub` and `update-initramfs -u`)

Make sure your card id is claimed by stub with:
`dmesg | grep pci-stub`